# python2 re.sub: abort catastrophic pattern on backtracking

Tags: python, regex

I am using `re.sub()`
with some complicated patterns (created by the code) that can cause backtracking.

Is there any practical way to abort `re.sub` (say pretend that pattern is not found, or raise an error) after a certain number of iterations in Python 2.6?

Sample (this is of course a dumb pattern, but it's created dynamically by a complex text processing engine):

`>>>re.sub('[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*[i1l!|](?:[^i1l!|\\w]|[i1l!|])*[l1i!|](?:[^l1i!||\\w]|[l1i!|])*','*','ilililililililililililililililililililililililililililililililililil :x')`

Comment: Could you post a sample?

Comment: ...what the hell??

Comment: are you sure your syntax is in format `re.sub(substring_to_be_replaced, new_string, Orignal_string, count)`

Answer (score 5):

Other than analyzing the regex for the potential of catastrophic backtracking (a hard problem with an external regex) or using a different regex engine that does not allow backtracking, I think the only way is with a timeout of this nature:

```
import re
import signal

class Timeout(Exception): 
    pass 

def try_one(pat,rep,s,t=3):
    def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
        raise Timeout()

    old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler) 
    signal.alarm(t) 

    try: 
        ret=re.sub(pat, rep, s)

    except Timeout:
        print('"{}" timed out after {} seconds'.format(pat,t))
        return None

    finally:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, old_handler) 

    signal.alarm(0)
    return ret

try_one(r'^(.+?)\1+$', r'\1' ,"a" * 1000000 + "b")
```

Trying to replace a large repetitions of a single character (in this case one million 'a' characters) is a [classic catastrophic regex failure](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). It would take tens of thousands of years to complete (at least with Python or Perl. Awk is different).

After 3 seconds of trying, it times out gracefully and prints:

```
"^(.+?)\1+$" timed out after 3 seconds
```

Comment: warning, `signal.SIGALARM` is platform dependent and doesn't play nicely in threaded environments

Comment: @the wolf: This works on Python 2.5+, but does not work on Python 2.4. On 2.4, when `re.sub(r'^(.+?)\1+$', r'\1' ,"a" * 1000000 + "b")` is executing, `signal.SIGALARM` seems to be ignored by the process. Is there a way to make it work on 2.4?

Comment: @mercador: You stated Python 2.6 in your question... Python 2.4 is nearly 9 years old. Perhaps it is safe to assume a newer version?

Comment: @the wolf: Yes, I did state Python 2.6. It turns out that two of our machines still have Python 2.4, and upgrading them would be a big ordeal now. They will be simply decommissioned at some point together with their Python 2.4. What I do not understand is that Python 2.4 has signal.alarm(), and it works, except that when you schedule an alarm and then run a **single** CPU intensive operation (like `re.sub`), the signal handler does not get called. If run a `while` loop instead, it does get called. Why is that? This behavior is different from 2.5 and 2.6, but does not seem to be documented?

Comment: @mercador: I do not know. I don't have Python 2.4 anymore, so I cannot check it.

Answer (score -1):

`count` can help you here:

```
In [9]: re.sub ?
Type:       function
Base Class: <type 'function'>
String Form:<function sub at 0x00AC7CF0>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       c:\python27\lib\re.py
Definition: re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
Docstring:
Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
a replacement string to be used.


In [13]: a = "bbbbbbb"

In [14]: x = re.sub('b', 'a', a, count=3)

In [15]: x
Out[15]: 'aaabbbb'
```

Comment: I do not see how it can help here; try the regex from my post with any count argument. From Python docs:

`The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced`

Comment: @mercador: Adding in a `count` keyword to your monstrosity of a regex does nothing to make my fans slow down.

Comment: @mercador: count will stop re.sub after a fixed number of iterations.. which is you question...